# Xamarin forms displaying data not in my layout

Tags: android, xamarin

So I just got started with Xamarin forms and I am trying to build a cross platform app for Android and iOS and it seems like we got a problem, the app for android says has a texview in the launch screen that says `Welcome to Xamarin Forms` but that does not exist in the `Tabbar.axml`and `Toolbar.axml` and neither is the text data modified from the cs code. So why is that happening, below is the code for the two layouts.

**Tabbar.axml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Toolbar.axml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

The two files above are the only layout files in my resources folder, I do not know why the app has a textview saying `Welcome to Xamarin Forms` why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/splashscreen

Comment: Xamarin Forms is about NOT touching platform-specific files (except when absolutely necessary). You are seeing [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows#customize-the-application). `MainPage.xaml`.

Comment: Sir, I have checked both the resources folder for the android platform and the iOS, I can assure you that there are only the files I pointed above for Android  and some `somefile.storyboard` for iOS.

Comment: I assumed he was seeing the splash screen, but @ToolmakerSteve is right.  If you are building a Xamarin Forms app, the entire point of Xamarin Forms is that you can build common UI in a shared project that will run on both Android and iOS.  The UI you are seeing is in that project, not the Android project.  I suggest you take the time to read the XF Docs to understand how this works.

Comment: @TechGeek - That's right. Those are the only files there for Android and iOS. Which has nothing to do with what you are seeing (other than establishing some basic colors etc.) The point of `Xamarin **Forms**` is to NOT need to put much in those projects. That's why I pointed to a portion of the tutorial for making your first XF app. Go through the entire tutorial, following its steps, and reading its explanation. OR perhaps you DON'T want the "cross-platform" UI of Xamarin Forms. See [Xamarin Android docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/) - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The IDE hide the MainPage.xaml inside the dependencies reference, why would IDE put layout files inside the dependencies ?